# Download mp4 video in several parts with curl then use ffmpeg on them

Tags: bash, curl, video, mp4

I want to download a video (.mp4) with curl but the file is too big, I can't download it in one go. So I try to download just a small part of the video with the --range option of curl, then I want to convert it with ffmpeg to get a lower quality and repeat the process until I get all parts. Unfortunately ffmpeg throw an error : "moov atom is not found". It seems that I need to have fragmented mp4, is curl able to do that ? What other solutions could I try ? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
ffmpeg do the job alone, no need to download the file in several parts, it can reduce the quality of the video as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/BlackLee/49cd6ae5cf6fbfc8651c)

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert part of an mp4, You need the entire thing. You can download all the parts, recreate the file in whole, then convert.